# Download file using window.location in a jhipster application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I want to download a file (.docx) from server in a Jhipster application.
I send back from server directly the binary content.

```
@GetMapping("/file/{id}")
@Timed
public void getFile(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = fileService.getFile(id);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    IOUtils.copy(stream,response.getOutputStream());
    stream.close();
}
```

I want now the user to be able to download the file.

In the controller of one of my pages I added this function, to test the download (or I directly type the url in a browser) :

```
function dwl (id) {
    window.location = "http://localhost:8080/#/file/"+id;
}
```

But I'm redirected to home page and no action is done on both server and client side.

Could you help me allowing request on the url?

Comment: Have you checked that your class hasn't a `@RequestMapping("/api")` annotation as JHipster generated resources have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost:8080/#/file/123` is *not* the same URL as `http://localhost:8080/file/123`.

The former simply loads `http://localhost:8080/` with `/file/123` as the [location hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash), whereas `http://localhost:8080/file/123` actually sends a request to your server for the `/file/123` path.

To download your file, you'll need to navigate the user to the latter:

```
window.location = "http://localhost:8080/file/" + id;
```

That said, you might not want to have them leave your application - in which case, you might be better off using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: If I try without # I get an error 404 not Found (even on other url of my application). This is an application generated with Jhipster.

Comment: @C.Cam: Those kinds of issues where there's several issues mixing together are always tricky to solve - glad we could help :)